# Combine data frames by pasting (adding) values from one into the other

Tags: r, insert, paste

I have two data frames (matrices). I want to past or add the values together, possibly by adding brackets. This is an example:
So I have 'x' and 'y'. I want to combine them so that I have 'z'.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(sample.int(6, size = 2*3, replace = TRUE), nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
y <- matrix(sample.int(6, size = 2*3, replace = TRUE), nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
z <- data.frame(c("2(6)", "3(4)"), c("4(4)", "6(1)"), c("2(2)", "6(2)"))
colnames(z) <- c("A1", "A2", "A3")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
matrix(paste0(x, "(",y,")"), dim(x), dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("A", 1:3)))

     A1     A2     A3    
[1,] "2(6)" "4(4)" "2(2)"
[2,] "3(4)" "6(1)" "6(2)"
```